# How do I make the read-only slave Postgresql12 database writable?

Tags: database, database-replication, postgresql-12

I created a standard PostgreSQL 12 replication configuration. I have changed hot_standby by off in postgresql.conf and entered the set transaction read only = off in psql. But still, I can not create a table or database and there are no I found how-to documents for the beginner. Could you please help me, how can I make writeable my replication database?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

stop postgresql service

```
systemctl stop postgresql
```

just delete standby.signal file under the /var/lib/postgresql/12/main

```
rm -rf standby.signal
```

Reconfigure pg_hba_conf and postgresql.conf file to the original version.